# Merge and sum similar CSV entries

Tags: python

Say my CSV file is like:

- love, like, 200
- love, like, 50
- say, claim, 30

where the numbers stand for the counts of those words co-occurring together in different contexts.

I want to combine the counts of the similar words. So I want to output something like:

- love, like, 250
- say, claim, 30

I've been looking around but it seems that I'm stuck with this simple issue.

Comment: Can you include an exact sample from the CSV? What have you tried already? Do you have any example code we can look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing an exact CSV its hard to know whats appropriate. The below code assumes the last token is a count, and it matches on everything before the last comma.

```
# You'd need to replace the below with the appropriate code to open your file
file = """love, like, 200
love, like, 50
love, 20
say, claim, 30"""
file = file.split("\n")

words = {}
for line in file:
    word,count=line.rsplit(",",1)   # Note this uses String.rsplit() NOT String.split()
    words[word] = words.get(word,0) + int(count)
for word in words:
    print word,": ",words[word]
```

And outputs this:

```
say, claim :  30
love :  20
love, like :  250
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly your application is, I think I would actually recommend using a Counter here. A Counter is a python collections module that lets you keep track of how many of everything there are. For example, in your situation you could just iteratively update a counter object.

for instance:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("your_file.txt", "rb") as source:
    counter = Counter()
    for line in source:
        entry, count = line.rsplit(",", 1)
        counter[entry] += int(count)
```

At which point you can either write the data back out as a csv or just continue to use it.